# Auth0 Sign in with Apple Integration for an Expo app

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, auth0

I have a react native expo app that I'm trying to publish to the App store via expo. When uploading this app to App Store Connect, I used the option to let Expo handle the configuration including setting up a distribution certificate, profile, and whatever other settings were necessary (everything was automatic - I just had to provide my login credentials for my account).

The issue I'm now having is that I need the **Client Secret Signing Key** for this app because I'm trying to implement **Sign in with Apple** for this app in Auth0. I was able to find the Client ID and Team ID, but I don't know where the Client Secret Signing Key is supposed to be. I've been reading the docs on Expo and Auth0, but I can't find the information. If anyone knows how I could obtain this information, I would greatly appreciate it. [image: Auth0 Social connections - apple integration]

Comment: I know I'm late, but you can create a key in the Apple developer console and download it, and copy and paste the key into the text box. https://marketplace.auth0.com/integrations/apple-social-connection